# input area stacking up after each submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, input

I amusing and Jquery Mobile, bootstrap and ajax to do an app and i encounter this situation in my input area where everytime i click the share button to post some info the the db
[image]

the input area keep stacking up each time i click the share button. However, it does not affect my textarea and everytime i refresh the page the input area went back to normal. whats wrong with the input area?

```
 My code: https://jsfiddle.net/k0q06eq2/1/
```

Comment: Provide your code on JsFiddle or CodePen

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/k0q06eq2/1/

Comment: @AlexanderKleinhans https://jsfiddle.net/k0q06eq2/1/

Comment: FYI you can't put PHP in the HTML input of JsFiddle.

Comment: Try pasting the source code from the web-browser instead.